# paypal recurring payments with nvp api version 65.1

Tags: paypal

Done a site which take recurring payments with paypal using a credit card. I now want to offer the user to the ability to use a paypal account to pay. I followed a guide and https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments

However paypal have updated their express checkout api so i cant find documentation which follows the api. I am wondering if some one has more up to date documentation on which fields i need to pass to paypal.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see required nvps to create recurring profile.
If you dont have a token (not a ExpressCheckout payment) then pass in CC details instead of token at bottom (as you do in DoDirect payment).

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
AppendPaypalAccountCreds(sb);
sb.Append("&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile");
sb.Append("&AMT=" + transaction.MoneyValue.ToString().Replace(",", "."));
sb.Append("&PROFILESTARTDATE=" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"));
sb.Append("&BILLINGPERIOD=" + transaction.RecurringPeriod);
sb.Append("&BILLINGFREQUENCY=" + GetRecurringFreq(transaction.RecurringPeriod));
sb.Append("&DESC=" + GetTransactionDesc(transaction));
sb.Append("&TOKEN=" + token);
```